# Redirect in a url created in a variable triggered by a button

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently using Wordpress. I created a button that once triggered will redirect a page that contains a parameter based on user id (For example: 
Example: http://www.example.com/"user id")

I am assuming that I am missing some codes. I keep getting an error stating: www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500.

I ran the php in a Wordpress plugin called "Woody Snippets" and it actually echoed the correct url. I did that to test if it would generate the correct url and it did. I am missing the code to actually get the "Current User id" and to redirect to the newly generated url.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    echo "www.example.com/" . $current_user_id . "<br>";
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="play_region.php" method="post">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.
Here is the new code:

```
`<?php
global $wpdb;
get_currentuserinfo();
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$url = "http://example.com/register/" . $current_user_id . "/32";
?>
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method = "post">
<input type="submit" value="Ready to Play">
</form>``
```

The code inside the form action is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution.

```
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $user->roles[0];
```

Comment: The current code in the php for grabbing the user id works. The issue is that I need help with the code to access the data base to pull the current user id and I need the code to input the new url to redirect the user to.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see off the bat is that your PHP code that echos your link is wrong. As written, the code will only echo the text of the link and not an actual link. You need to include the following in your echo statement to make a valid link.

```
<a href="link">link text</a>
```

Comment: I knew that the echo code was incorrect. I only used it to make sure the desired output of the url was correct.